# Не могу использовать итератор

Tags: c++, list, stl

Я пытаюсь сделать `list` объектов `Application`, чтобы можно было использовать итератор.

`Application` - класс содержащий два класса `Data` и дефолтные конструкторы

```
class Application {
std::string surname;
Data necessary;
Data available;
public: 
Application()
    :necessary(), available()
{
    surname = "";
}
~Application()
{}
void input_Application();
void output_Application();
```

};

Я добавил 3 объекта к `list`, после чего удалил 1 и все работает. После удаления размер составляет 2.

```
int main()
{
system("Color 0E");

std::list<Application*> accounting;

accounting.push_back(new Application());
accounting.push_back(new Application());
accounting.push_back(new Application());

accounting.erase(accounting.begin());
std::cout << accounting.size();

std::list<Application*>::iterator it;
it = accounting.begin();
it.

return 0;
}
```

**Однако я не могу получить доступ к этим объектам. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.**

Comment: Если я использую it->, то возникает ошибка: Error(active) E0131 *expression must have pointer - to - class type but it has type "Application **"*

Comment: Memory leak detected:)

Comment: Итератор указывает на указатель. Т.е. нужно разыменовать итератор, что бы получить указатель: `(*it)->`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. И простите что потратил время на такую ​​незначительную ошибку.